# opening a javafx FileChooser in the user directory

Tags: java, javafx-2

I am trying to open a javafx FileChooser in the user directory according to an example I found [here](http://blueskyworkshop.com/topics/Java-Pages/java-text-viewer/).

Here is a fragment of the simple code I am using:

```
FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
fc.setTitle("Open Dialog");
String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator;
file = new File(currentDir);
fc.setInitialDirectory(file);
```

However, I keep obtaining this warning (complete file paths have been truncated):

```
Invalid URL passed to an open/save panel: '/Users/my_user'.  Using 'file://localhost/Users/my_user/<etc>/' instead.
```

I verified that the `file` object is an existing directory adding these lines:

```
System.out.println(file.exists()); //true
System.out.println(file.isDirectory()); //true
```

Then I do not have idea why I am obtaining the warning message.

**UPDATE:**

This seems to be a bug in JavaFX: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8098160
(you need to create a free Jira account to see the bug report).
This problem happens in OSX, no idea about other platforms.

Answer (score 10):

This is what I ended up doing and it worked like a charm.

Also, make sure your folder is accessible when trying to read it (good practice).  You could create the file and then check if you can read it.  Full code would then look like this, defaulting to `c:` drive if you can't access user directory.

```java
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

//Extention filter
FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extentionFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("CSV files (*.csv)", "*.csv");
fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extentionFilter);

//Set to user directory or go to default if cannot access
String userDirectoryString = System.getProperty("user.home");
File userDirectory = new File(userDirectoryString);
if(!userDirectory.canRead()) {
    userDirectory = new File("c:/");
}
fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(userDirectory);

//Choose the file
File chosenFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
//Make sure a file was selected, if not return default
String path;
if(chosenFile != null) {
    path = chosenFile.getPath();
} else {
    //default return value
    path = null;
}
```

*This works on Windows and Linux, but might be different on other operating systems (not tested)*

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
file = new File(currentDir);
fc.setInitialDirectory(file);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@FXML private Label label1; //total file path print
@FXML private Label labelFirst; //file dir path print

private String firstPath; //dir path save

public void method() {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    if (firstPath != null) {
        File path = new File(firstPath);
        fileChooser.initialDirectoryProperty().set(path);   
    } 
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
            new ExtensionFilter("Text Files", "*.txt"),
            new ExtensionFilter("Image Files", "*.png", "*.jpg", "*.gif"),
            new ExtensionFilter("Audio Files", "*.wav", "*.mp3", "*.aac"),
            new ExtensionFilter("All Files", "*.*") );
    File selectFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(OwnStage);
    if (selectFile != null){
        String path = selectFile.getPath();
        int len = path.lastIndexOf("/"); //no detec return -1
        if (len == -1) {
            len = path.lastIndexOf("\\");
        }
        firstPath = path.substring(0, len);
        labelFirst.setText("file path : " + firstPath);
        label1.setText("First File Select: " + path);   
    }

  }
```